# Create a menu Bar in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a menu bar identical to the one in windows forms in my WPF application.

How would I do this?

The menu option in the WPF controls toolbox only gives a blank bar.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StackPanel></StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Why are there underscores? Why are they hidden?

Comment: @C4u: Those set the shortcut keys (eg. Alt+f for "file")

Comment: I have prepared a comprehensive tutorial on WPF Menus, Command Binding adding Shortcut keys etc at https://youtu.be/bdmVWGjpA_8

Answer (score 50):

Yes, a menu gives you the bar but it doesn't give you any *items* to put in the bar. You need something like (from one of my own projects):

```
<!-- Menu. -->
<Menu Width="Auto" Height="20" Background="#FFA9D1F4" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="_Emulator">
    <MenuItem Header="Load..." Click="MenuItem_Click" />
    <MenuItem Header="Load again" Click="menuEmulLoadLast" />
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click">
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock>Step</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Width="10"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">F2</TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
    :
```

Comment: Hi there, instead of that nested DockPanel, you can use the attribute InputGestureText instead. For example `<MenuItem Header="Step" Click="MenuItem_Click" InputGestureText="F2" />`

Comment: @AlanFoster You should post your own answer **including** that hint. I almost missed it and that's a shame! You can reuse the set up from the accepted answer. It's the most simple one, I'd say. And best formatted.

Answer (score 11):

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Menu Width="Auto" Height="20">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem x:Name="AppExit" Header="E_xit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="140" Click="AppExit_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Tools">
            <MenuItem x:Name="Options" Header="_Options" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="140"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Help">
            <MenuItem x:Name="About" Header="&amp;About" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="140"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Label Content="Label"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<Container>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New">
               <MenuItem Header="File1"/>
               <MenuItem Header="File2"/>
               <MenuItem Header="File3"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

A menu bar is not complete without sub menus, callbacks and tooltips:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Close" Click="MenuItem_Close_Click">
                <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Content="Close this application" />
                </MenuItem.ToolTip>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Help">
            <MenuItem Header="_About" Click="MenuItem_About_Click" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StackPanel>
       ... remainder of items for the form ...
```