# Menu does not stick on top WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Just look at images you will understand

When I starts program first view=>Click
[image]

When maximize its form its view=>Click
[image]

I am very new to WPF and I don't know how to fix this problem this is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Menu Margin="0,0,0,285">
            <MenuItem Header="File" Name="meFile"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit" Name="meEdit"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="View" Name="meView"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Project" Name="meProject"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Build" Name="meBuild"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Debug" Name="meDebug"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Team" Name="meTeam"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>


</Window>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Remove `Margin` altogether and use `VerticalAlignment="Top"` to make it work with `Grid`.
2. Don't use `Grid`, `DockPanel` is the way to go. Eg;

   ```
   <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
       <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
           <MenuItem Header="File" Name="meFile"></MenuItem>
           <MenuItem Header="Edit" Name="meEdit"></MenuItem>
           <MenuItem Header="View" Name="meView"></MenuItem>
           <MenuItem Header="Project" Name="meProject"></MenuItem>
           <MenuItem Header="Build" Name="meBuild"></MenuItem>
           <MenuItem Header="Debug" Name="meDebug"></MenuItem>
           <MenuItem Header="Team" Name="meTeam"></MenuItem>
       </Menu>
   </DockPanel>
   ```

You might need to set `Height` if you won't set `LastChildFill = False`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `DockPanel` as below..

```
<DockPanel>
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="File" Name="meFile"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Edit" Name="meEdit"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="View" Name="meView"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Project" Name="meProject"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Build" Name="meBuild"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Debug" Name="meDebug"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Team" Name="meTeam"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
<StackPanel></StackPanel>
```

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936796/create-a-menu-bar-in-wpf) as well.

Comment: Do I have to use dockpanel to make this.Is there any way to make this in grid?

Comment: `DockPanel` is better way to handle this case instead only use `Grid`