# How to properly create a sub-menu for a menu item in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently attempting to style my MenuItem objects in WPF/XAML, and I can't figure out how to output a sub-menu for a MenuItem. To be clear, this is the kind of thing I'm after:

[image]

And this is how I've currently styled my MenuItem:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GridLightColour}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Exo2Light}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource GridLightColour}" Background="{StaticResource GridLightColour}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header" Margin="7,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="0" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="-1">
                        <Border BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ButtonColour}" Background="{StaticResource GridLightColour}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="true" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuButtonMouseOverColour}" TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonMouseOverColour}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: What part of the menu's structure are you trying to change with the `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: Maybe this is the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936796/create-a-menu-bar-in-wpf

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm trying to add some kind of way to structure sub-menu items (like in the screenshot, if I hover over the "New" button, it opens another menu to the right). The current `ControlTemplate` works fine for the first level of menu items (https://imgur.com/S4bclJv) but if I try and add another level in the XAML, I get the sub-menu item showing up below instead of to the side, like so: https://imgur.com/S4bclJv

Comment: @Step You shouldn't have to modify the template at all for that, the `MenuItem` handles it by default.  Just nest MenuItems inside each other, I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're a XAML ninja, the best way to work with any template is to start by extracting the default template.

Because it is very very easy to totally break controls when you start doing this sort of stuff.  A template totally utterly replaces everything that makes up your control. In particular, be very careful to ensure any contentpresenter or named part is still in there once you finish.

Step by step:

Add a control of the type you want (menuitem) to a view.

Select it.

Over in the properties window find the Miscellaneous group.

Scroll down to template.

Click the little box on the right.

Choose Convert to new resource.

You can find you need to add references to stuff for some templates.

In any case, ensure that works.

You are now starting with a working template ( rather than a broken one ).

Make a small change and test.

Repeat.

Creep up on your requirement by a teeny tiny baby step at a time.

Also.

Rather than defining menuitems in code, template them out from a bound hierarchical collection.

Answer (score 1):

The default `MenuItem` already handles this kind of nesting by default.  There is no need to override the control's template to do it.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Open">
                <MenuItem Header="aaaaaaa" />
                <MenuItem Header="bbbbbbbb" />
                <MenuItem Header="ccccc" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Close" />
            <MenuItem Header="quit" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="Cut" />
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" />
            <MenuItem Header="Paste" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Grid />
</DockPanel>
```

Produces this result:

[image]

You can take this as far as you want to go, just keep nesting the items...

[image]

Comment: You're absolutely right, I found this out a lot later than I care to admit! Thing is, I've been trying to style my own MenuItems, but I can't quite figure out how while still maintaining this nesting behaviour with custom styling/templates. Simply changing Style properties doesn't seem to allow me to affect things like the outer border, check marks, arrows, etc.